# ruby xpath nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am using nokogiri ruby gem to parse xml.

```
<d:abc>19</d:abc>
<d:def m:type="Edm.Double">0</**d:def>
```

Assuming **entry** is XML Nokogiri node, using sample xml above. I could easily get the text of abc by using
**entry.xpath('d:abc').text**

How to get the text of **def**?

Thanks

Comment: Have you assured that the namespaces to which the prefixes `"d:"` and `"m:"` are bound, are registered with your XPath engine? Otherwise, you'll probably get an error.

Comment: hi, mu.. if you notice second XML element in the sample is "def"

Comment: hi Dimitre, i did not get any error for <d:abc>, but I can't figure out for <d:def  m:....>  , would you mind to elaborate what registration you're referring to? I get the XML from third party.. so I don't have a lot of flexibility to change the XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
xml = Nokogiri::XML('<root xmlns:m="bar"><def m:type="Edm.Double" /></root>')
p xml.at_xpath('//def').attribute('type').text
#=> "Edm.Double"
```

Comment: hi Phrogz.. thanks , I've edit your answer and accept as answer. Thanks!